# Bad reload after change input with Angularjs ngTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, ngtable

i have this problem:

i want to use ngTable with TableParams for load and change a table.

Here an example:

After the init of the page, if, for the first time, is inserted a number in the textbox, angular give me a number of rows in the table, but for the second (third...) if i insert other number, tha table not refresh.

```
  $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
            page: 1, // show first page
            count: 10 // count per page
        }, {
           total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
        params.total(data.length);
                $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xidius/781qkzq0/49/

i dont know if is possible use tableparams.reload() in this case.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

By defining `data` as a local variable in conjunction with `getData` callback, 
you have created an unnecessary closure, which seems to be not what you wanted.

Here is how you can fix the issue:

```
$scope.data = demoDataGenerator.generateData(intero);
$scope.cols = demoDataGenerator.generateColumns($scope.data[0]);

if (!$scope.tableParams) {
  $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page
    count: 10 // count per page
  }, {
    total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
      params.total($scope.data.length);
      $defer.resolve($scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
  });
} else {
    $scope.tableParams.total($scope.data.length);
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
}
```

Here is the corrected fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kx77f4xk/1/